# type mismatch between read and write methods wildfly 9.0.0

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, deployment, wildfly-9

I'm getting a error when I run my application in eclipse with wildfly 9.0.0.Final,
but with wildfly 8.0.0.Final it's working fine, it's the same code and configuration.

I'm working with hibernate.

I copy my server logs

```
11:16:01,536 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ws: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ws: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.ResidentService com.security.CustomFilter.residentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in "/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.ResidentService com.security.CustomFilter.residentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in "/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:224)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.ResidentService com.security.CustomFilter.residentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in "/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at com.profile.intializer.ApplicationContextInitializerForProfile.initialize(ApplicationContextInitializerForProfile.java:41)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.customizeContext(ContextLoader.java:499)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.ResidentService com.security.CustomFilter.residentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in "/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in "/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.findPropertyType(PropertyDescriptor.java:661)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.setReadMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfo.addOrUpdatePropertyDescriptor(ExtendedBeanInfo.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfo.addOrUpdatePropertyDescriptor(ExtendedBeanInfo.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfo.<init>(ExtendedBeanInfo.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:224)
    ... 42 more

11:16:01,552 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ws.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ws" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ws: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.ResidentService com.security.CustomFilter.residentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in \"/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class\": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.ResidentService com.security.CustomFilter.residentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in \"/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class\": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.ResidentService com.security.CustomFilter.residentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in \"/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class\": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.ResidentService com.security.CustomFilter.residentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in \"/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class\": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in \"/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class\": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods
    Caused by: java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods"}}
11:16:01,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ws.war" (runtime-name : "ws.war")
11:16:01,620 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ui-main.war" (runtime-name : "ui-main.war")
11:16:01,668 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ws: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ws: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.ResidentService com.security.CustomFilter.residentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'residentService' defined in "/C:/Program Files/WildFly/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ws.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/service/ResidentServiceImpl.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain BeanInfo for class [com.service.ResidentServiceImpl]; nested exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between read and write methods

11:16:02,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:16:02,125 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:16:02,125 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 21986ms - Started 520 of 708 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 246 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
11:16:02,188 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = ws.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
11:16:02,442 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment ws.war (runtime-name: ws.war) in 266ms
11:16:02,649 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "ws.war" (runtime-name: "ws.war")
11:16:02,653 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindErrorsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EscapeBodyTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.HtmlEscapeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.NestedPathTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.TransformTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ButtonTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxesTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.PasswordInputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.TextareaTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ws (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ws
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one solution, wildfly9 (with runtime jdk 1.8) in eclipse throw the error

```
type mismatch between read and write methods
```

the solution is:

- change the runtime for wildfly 9 for jdk 1.7
- check in the project: properties -> project facets -> java = 1.7
- check java compiler is jdk 1.7

at this moment jdk 8 is failing for me when I try to launch wildfly 9